# OpenSSO URL Policy Agent

Tags: opensso

How do I set the url for the URL Policy Agent? I currently have `http://*:*/*` and it works for most urls. Example url failures:

```
http://www.example.com/something?a=123
http://localhost:8081/app/servlet?sessionToken=476b71cb12f13d54af91a9636cf4b429
```

Example Error from log:

```
2009-08-05 11:48:35.890   Error 3648:108ca78 PolicyEngine: am_policy_evaluate: InternalException in Service::getPolicyResult() with error message:No Policy or Action decisions found found for resource: http://localhost:8081/app/servlet?sessionToken=476b71cb12f13d54af91a9636cf4b429 and code:7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new URL Policy Agent Rule with the '?' fixed the issue.

Example:
`http://*:*/*?*`